# Is there a way to upgrade your PowerApp after it is created?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a PowerApp I created a few months ago and I've noticed some differences in the PowerApps editor between my older apps and newly created apps.  For example, the way that you integrate a Power Automate flow looks completely different in the newer applications and is much better.  Ideally, I would like to integrate my flows using the same UI and methods in the older applications.

Is there a way to upgrade the PowerApps editor when modifying applications that were created previously or am I stuck with the older editor when modifying legacy apps?

Comment: what happens when you open your App in make.powerapps.com and browser powerapps editor? does it not automatically reflect new UI changes such as Adding flow button and so on?

Comment: Unfortunately no, and I am in the GCC just to note that..   But when I open my older apps, it still has the old method of adding flows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so my real issue was that I was looking for the new Power Automate pane on the left panel next to the Tree View, etc..  What I've learned is that this is a Preview Feature and needed to be enabled.

So I did that.

The authoring version can be changed in the Settings menu.

Answer (score 1):

You can push the PowerApps studio to a newer version or go back to a previous version. Its covered in the [PowerApps docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/studio-versions#change-power-apps-studio-version).

Be sure to read the Known Limitations section.

Alternatively, depending on the number of users, you may be able to export the app and import it as a new app. That *should* give a new authoring experience.

Comment: I'm going to look into this and report back.  Thank you for the idea!

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately.  I just (finally) gave it a try.